# Why this 'fail ->' caused invalid indentation error

Tags: coffeescript

This is my original code

```
  new Data({ data_id: @model.get 'id' })
    .fetch()
    .done (result) =>
      @_setUserInput(result.text)
    .fail ->
      bugsense.notify 'quickform results cannot be fetched'  # error here
```

It caused the coffeescript compiler to throw this error message: `Line contains inconsistent indentation (indentation)`

Then I rewrite to

```
  fail = -> bugsense.notify 'results cannot be fetched'

  new Data({ data_id: @model.get 'id' })
    .fetch()
    .done (result) =>
      @_setUserInput(result.text)
    .fail fail
```

It passes

My first version looks correct. So what it caused the invalid indentation error?

Comment: coffeescript.org seems fine with your original code so your problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have **tabs** and **spaces** mixed in your file, because I have tried to compile your code and It seems to be ok (you can check [here](http://coffeescript.org/#try:%20%20fail%20%3D%20-%3E%20bugsense.notify%20'results%20cannot%20be%20fetched'%0A%0A%20%20new%20Data(%7B%20data_id%3A%20%40model.get%20'id'%20%7D)%0A%20%20%20%20.fetch()%0A%20%20%20%20.done%20(result)%20%3D%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%40_setUserInput(result.text)%0A%20%20%20%20.fail%20fail) that your code is right).

If your file uses 2 or 4 spaces to indent, and you are mixing spaces with tabs your compilation is going to fail because your file has unconsistent indentation.